# Skia view element in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skia, skiasharp

I'm trying to draw new elements/images via the new skiasharp library for xamarin forms.
I got the samples working but they only change the full content page with the new canvas.

So my question would be how to implement a single view which can be placed in any place in another content page. Does anyone have experiences with skia?
How do I choose the canvas? Do I have to overwrite an existing Image or similar?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, and there is a view which you are looking for: [SkiaView](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/SkiaView.cs).

It inherited from [`Xamarin.Forms.View`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.View/) and contains some properties such as `HeightRequest` or `Scale`.

I suppose you are interested in these classes:

- [SkiaView](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/SkiaView.cs)
- [ISkiaViewController](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/ISkiaViewController.cs)
- [iOS - SkiaViewRenderer](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/iOS/SkiaViewRenderer.cs)
- [iOS - NativeSkiaView](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/iOS/NativeSkiaView.cs)
- [Android - SkiaViewRenderer](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/Droid/SkiaViewRenderer.cs)
- [Android - NativeSkiaView](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/5ff18f148e6c68c8ea2f927e09dc895a03047208/samples/Skia.Forms.Demo/Droid/NativeSkiaView.cs)

**EDIT**:

Finally there is a NuGet package with Xamarin.Forms support: [SkiaSharp.Views.Forms 1.54.1-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/1.54.1-beta1). Samples are available in [SkiaSharp repository](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/ca6f22751b0686c6dca1b87a5e882e3b7f6f7d02/samples/FormsSample/Core).

Comment: Hi Nikolai, thanks for your input... the hint with the HeightRequest was the thing I was missing.... Without a specific Height and Width the View ist not shown .... and yes of course this makes sense... :-)

Comment: These links seem to be outdated. What are the new classes for Skia and Xamarin Forms? I've been struggling to get a simple Hello World to show up.